# Proceeding to force close the producer since pending requests could not be completed within timeout 30000 ms

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

When I am trying to read large amount of data from the DB2 database, and writing to Kafka topic, getting this error -?
Proceeding to force close the producer since pending requests could not be completed within timeout 30000 ms. How to increase the timeout?

Comment: I was getting the issue due to kafka cluster issue. Two brokers were unresponsive which caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This message comes from the close() operation.

Spring normally never closes the producer until the application context is shut down.

You can increase this timeout on the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory`.

```java
    /**
     * The time to wait when physically closing the producer via the factory rather than
     * closing the producer itself (when {@link #reset()}, {@link #destroy()
     * #closeProducerFor(String)}, or {@link #closeThreadBoundProducer()} are invoked).
     * Specified in seconds; default {@link #DEFAULT_PHYSICAL_CLOSE_TIMEOUT}.
     * @param physicalCloseTimeout the timeout in seconds.
     * @since 1.0.7
     */
    public void setPhysicalCloseTimeout(int physicalCloseTimeout) {
        this.physicalCloseTimeout = Duration.ofSeconds(physicalCloseTimeout);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Gary. I was getting the issue due to kafka cluster issue. Two brokers were unresponsive which caused the issue.